# How to format an external hard disk

Tags: external-hdd, format

I tried formatting my external hard drive (Samsung Story Station 2TB) as it was not working well.
Now I'm getting an error and it's not working.

[image: Error message when I'm trying to format the disk]

Can anyone please help me with above error?

Comment: I see from that screenshot that the hard drive has a bad sector. I would not use that hard drive for data storage of any kind as it's possible that that drive won't last for long. About the question: did you try another filesystem?

Comment: By the way, you can select, copy & paste the text from most message and dialogue windows in Ubuntu (and Linux in general). It would be much better if you include the text in your question, because that makes it much easier for potential helpers to search for the error message elsewhere and for people with the same problem to find this question and its (hypothetical) answers.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to format the *unpartitioned* drive. File systems are supposed to be created inside partitions and therefore most file system creators refuse to create them on unpartitioned drives to avoid accidental misuse (unless you force them to).

You should create

1. a partition table on the drive (if none exists) and
2. at least one partition

before you create the file system. Gnome Disks (among other partition managers) can perform all of these tasks.

**Side note**: There is one known bad sector on the drive, which is a sign that the drive is likely to fail in the near future.